# Checking if firebase snapshot is equal to text field input

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check if the text input is equal to a value in the firebase database. I get below error

> "Snap (locations) null"

even when I enter a value that I know is in the DB. I would really appreciate some help :-) Below is my JSON file.

```
{
"locations" : {
"115 W Perry Carriage House" : {
  "City" : "Savannah",
  "State" : "GA",
  "img" : " "
},
"115 W Perry Street" : {
  "City" : "Savannah",
  "State" : "GA",
  "img" : " "
},
"117 West Charlton Street" : {
  "City" : "Savannah",
  "State" : "GA",
  "img" : " "
},
"127 Coming Street Unit C" : {
  "City" : "Charleston",
  "State" : "SC",
  "img" : " "
```

And the code:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("locations")
      .queryOrdered(byChild: "locations")
      .queryStarting(atValue: addressTextField.text)
      .observe(DataEventType.value, with: 
    { 
        (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
            if snapshot.exists(){
                print("Address is in DB")
            }else{
                print("Address doesn't exist")
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: I have also tried .queryEqual(toValue: addressTextField.text)

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text will allow us to see whether your query is correct, it makes the JSON searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen – I just added the the JSON as actual text. Sorry, it's my first post on stack overflow and I am still learning best practices!

Comment: No worries. We just needed to see the entire JSON. One more question: can you give an example value that you type into `addressTextField.text`? (using hardcoded values is almost always better in questions, because it removes a dependency on human input from the problem.)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "115 W Perry Street" for example

Comment: Got it! For that you'll need to use `queryOrderedByKey()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you're looking to filter on is the **key** of the node. So you'll need to call `queryOrderedByKey()`. Something like:

```
databaseRef.child("locations")
  .queryOrderedByKey()
  .queryStarting(atValue: addressTextField.text)
  .observe(DataEventType.value, with: 
{ 
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The query the code currently uses in your question is looking at the value of a child called "locations" nested under "locations". So if you imagine the query looking for data, it would pull the first child here, but not the second, for example.

```
{
"locations" : {
  "115 W Perry Carriage House" : {
    "locations": "115 W Perry Carriage House", // <- here's one!
    "City" : "Savannah",
    "State" : "GA",
    "img" : " "
  },
  "115 W Perry Street" : { // <- hmm...this one doesn't have "locations"
    "City" : "Savannah", 
    "State" : "GA",
    "img" : " "
  },
  //...
}
```

Since the data structure doesn't include any child called "locations", no value will ever match the one you're looking for. Since you want the address to match the key of the child, we can get the data of that child without a query. We can observe the exact path, like this:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
guard let text = addressTextField.text else { return }
databaseRef.child("locations/\(text)")
  .observe(.value, with:  { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
    if snapshot.exists() {
      print("Address is in DB")
    } else {
      print("Address doesn't exist")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jen, seems like a step in the right direction. That being said I'm still not getting the proper result. My snapshot comes out to be "Snap (Optional("32 Percy Street")) <null>".

Comment: Ah I see. This is one of the few disadvantages to showing your data structure instead of a screenshot of your code. Don't put your keys in quotes. So in your database, you see "32 Percy Street" in quotes? Add the same object but without quotes around the key. Then run the query again.

Comment: Hmm then I'm not sure what to tell you because I tested the exact use case and it worked for me https://ibb.co/ik99PT

Comment: Ah ok I tried with a TextField and it seems the issue may be that `addressTextField.text` is an optional String. I've updated my answer to unwrap it first. That seemed to fix it for me